# jQuery: Is using children() more efficient than using child selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors

I often need to setup jQuery events on li tags that don't have a class or ID associated with them like in this example:

```
    <div id="menu">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li>Nav Item 1</li>
        <li>Nav Item 2</li>
        <li>Nav Item 3</li>
        <li>Nav Item 4</li>
        <li>Nav Item 5</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

My understanding is that jQuery selecting reads from right to left so if I were to use a `$('#nav > li)` jquery selector it would have to search through all of the li tags and then evaluate whether the li tag had a parent with the id of nav.

Assuming this page has 30 li tags but I only want to select the 5 in the example, would it be more efficient to use `$('#nav').children('li')` ? My logic is that it will quickly find the #nav ID and then will only have 5 elements inside of it to search through.

An additional question I have is If there were more than 30 child elements to #nav would it then be more efficient to use the child selector `$('#nav > li')`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure, but my opinion is : when you can use CSS, use CSS. I don't actually know how jQuery understand #nav > li, but I always use CSS selectors when I can. That's a good question anyway.

Comment: If only there was a simple way to assess the (relative) efficiency of JavaScript, like [JS Perf](http://jsperf.com), for example…

Comment: I doubt you'd notice a difference either way with just 30 elements.

Comment: Find out: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/)

Comment: If you need to attach events, do not attach them to every element. Problem solved. `$("#nav").on("click","li", function() { console.log("this"); });`

Comment: @epascarello Thanks, should have thought of that. It didn't answer my question but solved my problem. This makes the most sense to do.

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks, didn't realize that existed. I'll use it out for testing next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having to try and create a custom selector, I was surprised to find that selectors are indeed evaluated *right to left.*

That means `$('#nav > li')` will first find all `LI`s in the page, then filter those to retain any having `id="nav"` in their immediate parent.

`$('#nav').children('li')` will be faster for the reasons above and what you assumed (which was correct).

The other side of the coin is "do you care?". If, for instance, you are only interested in mouse events, then the speed is driven by human interaction (at most a few times per second), whereas the speed difference in your selector methods would only be noticeable if you could do it 50,000 times per second. basically you will not normally care, but you should err on the side of efficiency when you can :)

if you were just after this to add mouse events, say `click`, using a single delegated event handler, attached to an ancestor element, will be very efficient:

e.g.

```
$("#nav").on('click', 'li', function() { 
    // DO SOMETHING HERE - "this" IS THE LI CLICKED 
});
```

This is efficient because it works as follows:

- Listen for click events bubbling up the DOM to the single `id="nav"` element we listen to.
- *Then* apply the jQuery selector against the elements in the bubble chain.
- *Then* apply the function *to the matching element that caused the event*.

This technique also means it will work for dynamically added objects as they only need to match the selector at event time (not event-registration time).

**Notes:**

- If no convenient ancestor is available to target, use `document` as the default for bubbled events.
- Do not use 'body' for delegated event handlers as styling can stop `body` receiving bubbled mouse events (if it has a calculated height of zero). Use `document` as your fallback.